# How to underline the section to the end of line?

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I am using the following code taken from online to underline the section title

```
\makeatletter
\sectionfont{\ulemheading{\uuline}}
\let\oldsection\section
\def\section{\@ifstar\s@section\@section}
\newcommand{\@section}[2][\relax]{\oldsection{\llap{\rlap{\hspace{\textwidth}\llap{#1}}\protect\phantom{\thesection\quad}}#2}}
\newcommand{\s@section}[2][\relax]{\oldsection*{\llap{\rlap{\hspace{\textwidth}\llap{#1}}}#2}}
\makeatother
```

After this code, I use `\section` and I get the following:

[image]

However, I want the underline to go to the end of the line that looks like the following:

[image]

I try to add space in the section title by hand, but it turns out to be hard to tune, especially because I have so many sections.

How can I have the underline go to the edge of the page?

Answer (score 1):

It is better to draw the rule directly instead of using `\uuline`.  An easy way to draw a rule that extends the whole width of the text is `\hrule`.  For example:

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldsection\section
\def\section{\@ifstar\s@section\@section}
\newcommand{\@section}[2][\relax]{\oldsection[#1]{#2}\hrule\bigskip}
\newcommand{\s@section}[1]{\oldsection*{#1}\hrule\bigskip}
\makeatother
```

You can fine tune the position of the line by adding positive or negative `\vspace` around the `\hrule`.

### Remarks about the MWE:

If I understand correctly, your idea is the following:

1. use the `\sectionfont{\ulemheading{\uuline}}` to underline the section name.
2. change the width of the section title to textwidth, in order to extend the underline.

While that might work in your setting, this is not a good idea in general, since this will also mess up a possible table of contents.

I don't completely understand what your MWE does (or what it is supposed to do), but after the definitions in your MWE, both `\section` and `\section*` accept an optional argument, which is typeset flushed to the right.  This is not standard behaviour of LaTeX: Usually, only `\section` should accept an optional argument, which should be a variant of the section title for the table of contents.  `\section*` does not add an entry to the table of contents, and thus does not need the optional argument.  Thus, `\@section` should have two arguments, of which `#2` is the section title, and `\s@section` should have one argument, the section title.

EDIT:

- imitating the MWE, now the `*` and the optional argument `[]` also work.
- explaining issues with MWE

Comment: do you mean rather "fine tune the position... using `\vspace`" and not `\hspace` ?

Comment: @jfbu yes, of course, thanks.  I corrected it.